# How to disable chrome dev tools waterfall?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm a bit constrained by screen space, and i want to hide waterfall in chrome dev tools network tab. I googled / searched through all settings / options, but i can't find any option to disable / hide it. Any hint ?

[image]

Comment: This is a dev tool.. there are lots of other chrome devtools usage questions here.

Comment: Yes, this question is completely valid and is exactly why we have the DevTools channel here on Stack Overflow. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

DevTools tech writer here. Doesn't look like there's a way to do this, currently.

You can hide other columns by right-clicking the table header, and unchecking the ones you want to hide.

You can also drag the bar separating the waterfall from the item to its left in order to minimize it.

Comment: Yes but the waterfall have a minimum width, we cannot shrink it to zero.. anyway "no way to do this" is an answer :)

Comment: The DevTools team agrees that it should be possible, though. I created a request for the feature: https://crbug.com/839997

Comment: Yes, it sucks. It's one of those things that looks small but has big technical debt underneath. Hence why there's been no movement on the topic.

Comment: any progress on this?? 2+ years folks 0_o

Comment: @anatol I guess not; according to that DevTools link above posted by Kayce and I'm not seeing the option when checking my current version of Google Chrome or Chromium which are both running version 90 something. Chromium is slightly more advanced as expected.

Comment: 5 years and no change, typical for Google products. Took them over a decade to implement usable volume steps on Android, so I'm not even remotely surprised this isn't being worked on...

Comment: It's the most **useless** thing. Just remove it.

Comment: lol, almost 6 years later and it's still there, goes to show how much google cares about the developer experience.

Answer (score 3):

[This may help, Remove Chrome Network timeline](https://superuser.com/a/1117776/992093)

"Show overview" Button Toggles the network timeline

Comment: But the problem (still unresolved on Chrome side) is removing the "Waterfall", not the "Network timeline"...

Answer (score 1):

We're very close to having the option to hide the Waterfall! It's not in Chrome yet(or whatever chromium spin-off browser you use), but, it is in the latest Chromium build!

https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/5372690

[image]